# How can I reduce the quality of an uploading image using Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to reduce the quality of an uploading image using the Paperclip plugin/gem. **How can I do that?**

---

At this time in my model file I have:

```
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :styles      => {
      :thumb     => ["50x50#",   :jpg],
      :medium    => ["250x250#", :jpg],
      :original  => ["600x600#", :jpg] }
```

that will convert images in to the `.jpg` format and will set dimensions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try using convert_options.

```
has_attached_file :avatar, 
                  :styles          => { :thumb => '50x50#' },
                  :convert_options => { :thumb => '-quality 80' }
```

Answer (score 11):

From the [paperclip wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#optimizing-thumbnails-for-the-web), there's an option for quality:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo,
                    :styles => {
                      :small => {
                        :geometry => '38x38#',
                        :quality => 40,
                        :format => 'JPG'
                      },
                      :medium => {
                        :geometry => '92x92#',
                        :quality => 50
                      }
end
```

Comment: I made like that, but it seams don't work: Paperclip doesn't reduce the image quality! I tryed also to restart the server.

Comment: It worked for me. Make sure, if you're in a rails console and running the reprocessing, to exit and run rails console again, because otherwise it won't pick up the model changes.

Comment: This solution appears to be deprecated. The wiki link cited as the source is now broken, and my effort to implement it this way did not work.

Answer (score 3):

As James says, once you figure out the correct arguments to pass to ImageMagick's `convert` by experimenting on the command line, you can pass these in to Paperclip through the `convert_options` option as in James' example.

If you have multiple arguments, pass them in as an array. Here's an example which I laboured over for a while:

```
:convert_options => {:medium => ["-shave", "2x2", "-background", "white", 
                                 "-gravity", "center", "-extent", 
                                 "530x322", "+repage"],
                     :small  => ["-shave", "1x1"] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Except `-quality`, the `-strip` option of `ImageMagick` can remove all profile and other fluff from the image which may reduce more size

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
  :thumb => "100x100#" },
  :convert_options => {
  :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip" }
```