# Is it possible to compress the size (bytes) of an image to a specific size using Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, compression, paperclip

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to know if it is possible to compress the size (bytes) of an image to a specific size using the Paperclip plugin/gem.

For example, if I upload an image of 1500kb, I would like to have a thumb resized to 10kb.

At this time in my model file I have:

```
:styles       => {
  :thumb      => {
    :geometry => '50x50#',
    :quality  => 50,
    :format   => :jpg
  },
}
```

If so, how to do that?

Comment: Does this answer help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988527/ruby-on-rails-how-to-reduce-the-quality-of-an-uploading-image-using-paperclip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that there's a way to compress something to a *specific* output size.  For one thing, it may not be possible to compress something down to that size.  With Jpeg you can adjust the 'quality' parameter but there's no real way to predict what the exact compression ratio will be.

If all you need is thumbnails that are under a certain file size, try compressing the image at one 'quality' value and then incrementally adjusting it until the output size meets your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

`Paperclip` processes image based on `ImageMagick`

As far as I know, there is no an option of `ImageMagick` can specify the size of the output image.

But you can change the dimension or the quality of the image to reduce the size.

You can use `-quality`option to adjust the quality level from 1 to 100 and the `-strip` option can remove all profile and other fluff from the image

```
has_attached_file :photo,
  :styles => {
  :thumb => "100x100#" },
  :convert_options => {
  :thumb => "-quality 75 -strip" }
```

[Paperclip wiki](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation#optimizing-thumbnails-for-the-web)

[ImageMagick options](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize)